# How to create my own Joomla distribution with the extensions I always use?

Tags: joomla-3.x, integration

I want to make "My Own Joomla". Instead of creating my sites starting from vannilla blank Joomla installation, and then manually adding my favorite extensions and configuring my favorite options and settings, I want to make my own pre-made Joomla site, and to use it as "template" for my future sites, thus speeding up that process.

What are the best practices in achieving such a goal?

Comment: Dump the SQL, download a fresh copy of Joomla, then replace the `testing` sql file in the installation folder. On my phone so cant post a detailed answer so hopefully you get the main gist

Comment: To complement, don't forget to frequently update the core and extensions (_components, modules, templates, etc_) that you will use, mainly for security or performance reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have built your standard Joomla website with your preferred extensions and settings, take a backup of the website using Akeeba backup.

Whenever you build a new website, all you need to do is create the database and then use [Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html) and the backup file to create a new copy of your website.

Using this method to deploy your standard Joomla install only takes about 10 minutes or so from start to finish.

The free versions of Akeeba Backup and Akeeba Kickstart work fine for this.

Comment: Yes. I use this method too.

Comment: There are even ways to bypass the backup, download, upload and kickstart steps.  Using Akeeba Backup, you can quickly transfer a clone of your site from one host to another in a matter in few minutes using "Site Transfer" tools.  See Akeeba's Site Transfer Wizard at https://www.akeebabackup.com/videos/1212-akeeba-backup-core/1619-abtc05-site-transfer-wizard.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @NivF007, somehow I hadn't noticed this feature yet.